# Typing animation CSS going beyond specified width limit

Tags: html, css

If you run the code snippet attached, you'll see that the "execute myProfile" typing animation is expanding too much; way beyond the width I've specified for the heading.

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira);

body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    font-family: 'Saira', sans-serif;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.exec{
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 2px orange;
    padding-right: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    font-weight: lighter;
    margin: 0 auto;
    animation:
        typing 1s steps(20, end),
        cursor 0.5s step-end infinite;

}
@keyframes typing{
    from{width: 0}
    to{width: 100%}
}
@keyframes cursor{
    from, to {
        border-color: transparent;}
    50% {
        border-color: orange;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <h2 class="exec">execute myProfile();</h2>
</body>
```

I made this animation yesterday and that typing animation works perfectly. The code is about the same yet producing different results. Why is it so?

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Teko);
body{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background-color: #3c3f41;
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}
.exec h2{
    color: #fff;
    font-family: 'Teko', sans-serif;
    font-weight: lighter;
    overflow: hidden;
    border-right: 2px solid orange;
    padding-right: 5px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    margin: 0 auto;
    animation:
        typing 1s steps(20, end),
        cursor 0.5s step-end infinite;
    /*animation-delay: 5s;*/
}
@keyframes typing{
    from{ width: 0 }
    to{ width: 100% }
}
@keyframes cursor{
    from, to {
        border-color: transparent;}
    50% {
        border-color: orange;
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="exec">
        <h2>
            execute portfolio;
        </h2>
    </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Where did you specify the width for `h2`, because all I see is that `body` is `100vw` and `h2` is default auto width. Is above your actual code? Because if it is, you should just specify width for `h2`.

Comment: but you see in the second code, it was even working without specifying the width.
specifying it was adding some animation problems so i removed it.

Comment: @TalhaMunir It worked on the second exemple because you actually put the H2 inside a div. If you add a div to your first exemple, it work : [link](https://jsfiddle.net/uz82htm1/1//)

Comment: You need to specify the width when it's a child of `body`. You have set `margin: 0 auto`, so it's horizontal center aligned, but through the entire body width (100vw). Try something for `.exec { width: 60%; }`.

Comment: you're right! it does work simply by adding inside a div. Thanks. I thought it wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try putting the animation onto an inner span so that you can keep the size of the h2 to the size of it's text:

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Saira);
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  font-family: 'Saira', sans-serif;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.exec {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align:center;
}

.animation {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-right: 2px solid orange;
  padding-right: 5px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  font-weight: lighter;
  margin: 0 auto;
  animation: typing 1s steps(20, end), cursor 0.5s step-end infinite;
}

@keyframes typing {
  from {
    width: 0
  }
  to {
    width: 100%
  }
}

@keyframes cursor {
  from,
  to {
    border-color: transparent;
  }
  50% {
    border-color: orange;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h2 class="exec"><span class="animation">execute myProfile();</span></h2>
</body>
```